# Por que estes dois códigos idênticos, um em C++ e outro e Java, dão resultados diferentes?

Tags: java, c++, float, double

Estou tentando resolver [uma questão no URI Online Judge](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2758) em Java porém estou recendo 5% de erro, e pelo que estudei está sendo causado pelo fato que a precisão das variáveis em C++ e em Java é diferente. Eu já tentei de tudo para tentar conseguir Accept em Java mas não consegui... Eu "converti" o código de Java para C++ e funcionou perfeitamente.

Eu já tentei usar o `strictfp`, já tentei usar `BigDecimal`, já tentei alterar a precisão do `BigDecimal`, tentei alterar as variáveis, tentei alterar os métodos de *print*, tentei usar outros modificadores mas não consegui em nada, então tudo leva a crer que a culpa é da precisão dos valores de ponto flutuante.

Java Code:

```
Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
float a = leitor.nextFloat();
float b = leitor.nextFloat();
double c = leitor.nextDouble();
double d = leitor.nextDouble(); 
System.out.printf("A = %f, B = %f\n",a,b);
System.out.printf("C = %f, D = %f\n",c,d);
System.out.printf("A = %.1f, B = %.1f\n",a,b);
System.out.printf("C = %.1f, D = %.1f\n",c,d);
System.out.printf("A = %.2f, B = %.2f\n",a,b);
System.out.printf("C = %.2f, D = %.2f\n",c,d);
System.out.printf("A = %.3f, B = %.3f\n",a,b);
System.out.printf("C = %.3f, D = %.3f\n",c,d);
System.out.printf("A = %.3E, B = %.3E\n",a,b);
System.out.printf("C = %.3E, D = %.3E\n",c,d);
System.out.printf("A = %.0f, B = %.0f\n",a,b);
System.out.printf("C = %.0f, D = %.0f\n",c,d);
```

C++ code:

```
float  a, b;
double c, d;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cin >> c;
cin >> d;
printf("A = %f, B = %f\n",a,b);
printf("C = %f, D = %f\n",c,d);
printf("A = %.1f, B = %.1f\n",a,b);
printf("C = %.1f, D = %.1f\n",c,d);
printf("A = %.2f, B = %.2f\n",a,b);
printf("C = %.2f, D = %.2f\n",c,d);
printf("A = %.3f, B = %.3f\n",a,b);
printf("C = %.3f, D = %.3f\n",c,d);
printf("A = %.3E, B = %.3E\n",a,b);
printf("C = %.3E, D = %.3E\n",c,d);
printf("A = %.0f, B = %.0f\n",a,b);
printf("C = %.0f, D = %.0f\n",c,d);
```

Os resultados em C++ estão saindo 5% diferentes dos resultados em Java. Infelizmente eu não tenho acesso aos resultados só tenho acesso a resposta do site.

Comment: Quais os valores com que está a testar ? O @bfavaretto mostrou um exemplo no Ideone em que a saída é exatamente a mesma.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não possuo os valores de entrada. Estou tentando resolver esta questão do URI https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2758

Answer (score 3):

Não é tão incomum as linguagens terem implementações de ponto flutuante de forma diferente entre si. Claro, elas não estão seguindo fielmente a especificação IEEE

Uma possível solução é usar em Java [`strictfp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp) (ligando na compilação também) e pode ser que obtenha o mesmo resultado.

Mas de qualquer forma não faz tanta diferença porque números de ponto flutuante binários foram criados para serem rápidos e não para serem exatos. Se precisa de exatidão está usando o tipo errado, provavelmente quer usar o [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Veja mais em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Com a edição está dito que já fez o sugerido, mas não vimos o que. É possível que o exercício só tenha sido testado com C++ e não consiga fazer em outra linguagem. Não temos como saber.

Comment: E mais, testando os códigos não vi diferença na saída. Possivelmente, depende da entrada. Ver https://ideone.com/flx87K e https://ideone.com/al6K7R.

Comment: Possivelmente..

Comment: Estou tentando resolver esta questão no URI: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2758 Eu estou submetendo em Java e esta dando 5% de erro, quando tento submeter em C++ funciona perfeitamente. Os números de entrada não são fornecidos para os usuarios (infelizmente) então não podemos saber onde esta o erro.

Comment: Eu tentei de TUDO para resolver está questão... a minha ultima saida foi vir para o stackoverflow... já tinha tentando o strictfp, tentado BigDecimal, já tentei usar outros tipos de variaveis também, tentei alterar a maneira de como os resultados são printados na tela, eu realmente já tentei de tudo mas continuo recebendo 5% de erro e pelo que eu estudei essa diferença é gerada por causa da precisão das variaveis. posso estar enganado.

Comment: Estou saindo em viagem agora e não posso ver, mas quando tem um problema específico poste ele. Eu te mostrei o que você perguntou. Se tentou outras coisas deveria ter postado tudo.

Comment: Desculpe pelo incomodo, irei editar o tópico agora e colocarei mais informações.

Comment: Acabei de editar o tópico trocando a descrição e adicionando algumas novas informações espero que isso ajude.

Comment: @EduardoMior o problema é que agora você mudou a pergunta, não sei se eu quero ou posso responder essa pergunta nova, eu respondi a original, e nova no fundo mostra outro problema, não o original perguntado. E colocou algo que não temos como verificar. Você diz que fez, mas e se fez algo errado. Não disse como fez. È impossível dar errado se fez certo, então fez errado, mas não temos como saber neste pergunta.

Comment: ???????? Você quer dizer que a != a sendo que a == a != b ... o problema no final das contas era o format do java.... o %.f do java é diferente do %.f do c++